# Wrap ES6 Module around React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using react and ES6.

I have a file called:

```
mainComponent.js
```

To use this on other files I just import the component.

What I want to do now is to wrap the component(s) inside an ES6 Module so that I just need to use import on the module to have access to the component(s)

For example:

If I had 2 component:

```
reactComponent1.js
reactComponent2.js
```

Then I want to wrap these 2 components in wrapperModule.js

So that if I want to use these components I just import wrapperModule.js

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use it like this

```
wrapperModule.js
export { ReactComponent1 } from 'path/to/reactComponent1'
export { ReactComponent2 } from 'path/to/reactComponent2'
```

And use it in your file like this

```
import {ReactComponent1, ReactComponent2 } from 'path/to/wrapperModule'
```